# Install android old system images (ABIs) from the command line

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

From the sdk manager you can easily tick the checkboxes and you get system images (for instance, `ARM EABI v7a System Image`) installed and available to create AVDs.

My problem is that the system where I'm trying to create an AVD is headless and so I cannot open the sdk manager. I'm force to install system images from the command line.

It was easy to install targets by running `$ android update sdk --no-ui` (all targets where installed actually but without system images except of the newest target "android-17"). Now, how do I install system images for "android-15"?

When I try `$ android update sdk --no-ui --filter "sysimg-15"` the result is

```
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'sysimg-15'.
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

Unfortunately google/stackoverflow didn't help me.

Comment: IIRC these are just zip files unpacked in the right location.  If you can install them first on a headful machine, you can copy the platform directories etc over to the headless one.  Otherwise you can find the archives by looking through the xml and install them manually.

Comment: This sounds like a proper manual installation. I'll try it if I do not find a proper way using `android sdk` command line. Cheers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The option `--all` or `-a` is the answer:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "sysimg-15"
```

Not including `--all`, the android updater takes only the latest package (sysimg-17) into account ignoring older packages. Including all packages with `-a` allows you to filter (and so get installed) any sysimg.

Comment: It seems that this command is no longer valid, as it won't result in any SDK components being installed. Is there a newer version to do the same from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use the GUI through X11 forwarding in this case?

Using Linux: [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-mac-osx-x11-forwarding-over-ssh-howto.html)

Using Windows: [Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html)

Comment: It would if the target machine runs linux and has the X11 client libs on it; many headless (server install) machines may not, though they can be installed if that is permissible.

Comment: I tried that, but without success. Therefore I said from the command line in the title. Android is headless on that machine exactly because the machine is not prepared to run X. Xvfb is available though, but not enough to run the GUI. `swt-pi-gtk` is missed. I do believe, there must be an easy way to run such installation from the command line.

Comment: @Al_ I don't believe there is a command line version of the official install, but it's not hard to duplicate its actions.  You can try do searches on sdk offline install - it's been discussed many places before.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I found a solution that maybe interests you. Check my answer. Many thanks for your suggestions. They could work as well.

Comment: Nice! Had not realized they had these switches