# android sdk missing system-images

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to setup multiple target on a CI server (CentOS 64_x86) for automated Android app testing, which would run multiple emulator heedlessly. After extracting the latest SDK from 
    http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729.zip
and run,
    android update sdk --no-ui
I suppose I should have installed all existing component properly, but 2 problems found,

1. After selected "ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18" and agreed "android-sdk-license-bcbbd656", it seems installed properly but next time I update sdk it shows up again and always installable. Note that I installed them through command line where no window UI available, not sure if any difference here.. (however the emulator for API 18 is working...)
2. Looking at the folder $SDK_PATH/system-images, only "android-18/armeabi-v7a" available, but compared to my another SDK installation on macbook, this same folder contains much richer content including whatever api available, not only API 18.
3. I guess this difference above caused my 3rd issue (for example on API 15 which don't have a "system-images/android-18/armeabi-v7a"), when I run lator from an AVD like,

> emulator -no-window -port 5554 -snapshot default -avd google_api_15

error happens

```
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/abc/adt/sdk/platforms/android-15/skins/WVGA800/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
```

comparing to a normal output this should be

> emulator: skin network speed: 'full' emulator: skin network delay:
>   'none' emulator: autoconfig: -kernel
>   /home/bamboo_master/environment/adt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//kernel-qemu
>   emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk
>   /home/bamboo_master/environment/adt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//ramdisk.img
>   emulator: Using initial system image:
>   /home/bamboo_master/environment/adt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//system.img
>   emulator: autoconfig: -data
>   /home/bamboo_master/.android/avd/google_api_15.avd/userdata-qemu.img
>   emulator: autoconfig: -initdata
>   /home/bamboo_master/.android/avd/google_api_15.avd/userdata.img
>   emulator: autoconfig: -cache
>   /home/bamboo_master/.android/avd/google_api_15.avd/cache.img emulator:
>   autoconfig: -snapstorage
>   /home/bamboo_master/.android/avd/google_api_15.avd/snapshots.img
>   emulator: Physical RAM size: 1024MB

If my understanding is right that it's due to system-image missing, is there a way to install them? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by this post, I can install other system-images using

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all
```

[Install android old system images (ABIs) from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707238/install-android-old-system-images-abis-from-the-command-line)

However I'm still testing.. : )